No constructor for type 'Umbraco.Cms.Core.PropertyEditors.PropertyEditorCollection' can be instantiated using services from the service container
I upgraded a website from Umbraco 9 to 13, can go into the back office and look at all the content, but unable to publish any content. This is my startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddUmbraco(env, config)
        .AddBackOffice()
        .AddWebsite()
        .AddComposers()
        .Build();
}

I have tried to add the class, BuilderCollectionBase, which the PropertyEditorCollection inherits from to the service container.
